# C+ how to change array of chars in function

Tags: c++, pointers

I have this header:

```
MvProjectQueue & operator >> (char *);
```

And I have to write a function meeting this spec. (my function should "return" an array of chars using `>>` operator)

I have to change the passed argument, i.e. I get an array of char when my function is called and I have to modify it (in place).

Normally I would use

```
MvProjectQueue & operator >> (char **);
```

got a pointer to `char *` and I would solved it easily, using something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class SimpleShowcaseObject
{
public:
    SimpleShowcaseObject(){};
    ~SimpleShowcaseObject(){};

    SimpleShowcaseObject & operator >> (char ** p_ch)
    {
        *p_ch = "changed";
        cout << "in scope: " << *p_ch << endl;

        return *this;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    char *ch = new char[10];

    ch = "hello";
    SimpleShowcaseObject o = SimpleShowcaseObject();

    cout << "original: " << ch << endl;
    o >> &ch;
    cout <<"changed: " << ch << endl;

    delete[] ch;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

But this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class SimpleShowcaseObject
{
public:
    SimpleShowcaseObject(){};
    ~SimpleShowcaseObject(){};

    SimpleShowcaseObject & operator >> (char *ch)
    {
        ch = "changed";
        cout << "in scope: " << ch << endl;

        return *this;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    char *ch = new char[10];

    ch = "hello";
    SimpleShowcaseObject o = SimpleShowcaseObject();

    cout << "original: " << ch << endl;
    o >> ch;
    cout <<"changed: " << ch << endl;

    delete[] ch;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

executes and prints:

```
original: hello
in scope: changed
changed: hello
```

and I would like to have

```
original: hello
in scope: changed
changed: changed
```

(edited several times, big thanks to everyone for trying to help!)

Comment: ... so did you solve the problem?

Comment: not yet, the problem is that i _have_ _to_ use the header above

Comment: You could pass an allocated char array and copy to it in your operator, but then of course the function could not control the length of the array. This really does not look like a method that returns a char*.

Comment: It appears that the calling code is responsible for ensuring that the pointer points to an array that is big enough for the operation. It's a bad design, but it's not illegal; just assume that the array is there, and modify it. What's the problem?

Comment: Yes, it is a bad design. The problem is that I don't know how to modify the passed array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function receive what should be a buffer you can write to:

```
SimpleShowcaseObject & operator >> (char *ch)
{
    //ch = "changed";// with this you are changing the value of the pointer, not what you want
    strcpy (ch, "changed");
    cout << "in scope: " << ch << endl;

    return *this;
}
```

As other have already pointed out, this is not a good design: your `operator >>` has to write a string (`char[]`) in a buffer, without knowing the lenght of input buffer; not a nice scenario.